# Get product total sales based on order status in WooCommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I use product meta `total_sales` to display the total sales of a product, on the single product page in WooCommerce:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wc_product_sold_count() {
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'total_sales', true );
    echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
```

But when some orders are canceled, the total sales are not automatically decreased. So, how can I get the total sales based on order status in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the total sales, based on order statuses, you will have to use a custom function:

```php
function get_product_total_sales_by_order_status( $product_id, $order_statuses ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT SUM( opl.product_qty ) 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_order_product_lookup as opl
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        ON opl.order_id = p.ID
        AND p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "', 'wc-", $order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND opl.product_id = %d
    ", $product_id ) );
}
```

Which can then be used as:

```php
// Set the product ID
$p_id = 30;

// Set the orders statuses (without wc-)
$statuses = array( 'on-hold', 'processing', 'completed' );

// Call function, display result
echo get_product_total_sales_by_order_status( $p_id, $statuses );
```

---

Or in your specific case:

```php
function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Set the orders statuses (without wc-)
        $statuses = array( 'completed' );

        // Call function
        $total_sales = get_product_total_sales_by_order_status( $product->get_id(), $statuses );

        // Display result
        if ( $total_sales >= 1 ) {
            echo sprintf( __( 'Total sales: %d', 'woocommerce' ), $total_sales );
        } else {
            echo __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 11 );
```